# c++ why is my code creating extra elements in my vector?

Tags: c++, vector

My code counts the frequency of letters in a file. My code:

```
void incCount (int i, vector<CCount> &chars)
{
    int n;
    n = chars[i].i;
    n++;
    chars[i].i = n;
}

void procWord(string word, vector<CCount> &chars)
{
    for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
    {
        bool found = false;
        char a = word[i];
        for (int j=0; j<chars.size(); j++)
        {
            if (a == chars[j].c)
            {
                bool found = true;
                incCount(j, chars);
            }
        }
        if (found == false)
        {
            CCount c; //CCount is a class with a char and int data type.
            c.c = a;
            c.i = 1;
            chars.push_back(c);
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    vector<CCount> chars;
    string word;
    //opening file code here

    while (fin >> word) {
        procWord(word, chars);
    }    
    return 0;
}


class CCount
{
    public:
        char c;
        int i;
};
```

the code does accumulate the letter count however when i print the the vector elements I get [this](http://imgur.com/CtdsPNZ). I use "this is a test data" as the test input in the file

Comment: its a simple class with 2 data members char and int

Comment: Fyi, you can speed this up significantly by tossing most of it and using `std::map<char,unsigned>`. Regardless, good luck with your histogram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining `found` again. See commented line.

You are defining variable with same name and most local variable will be preferred.

```
    bool found = false; 

    char a = word[i];
    for (int j=0; j<chars.size(); j++)
    {
        if (a == chars[j].c)
        {
            bool found = true; //this is wrong, just make it found = true;
            incCount(j, chars);
        }
    }
```